# How can I more precisely translate 通过联接功能简单的终端共享计算机，以虚拟技术把大计算机资源分割给以终端对应用用户使用?

Tags: translation, meaning, technology

I'm struggling with the reading and the translation of a computer text, precisely concerning cloud computing and the history of computing in general.  In particular, there is one sentence that is causing me several problems.

"20 世纪60 年代，计算机水平低、成本高，只能建以大计算机为中心的机房，**通过联接功能简单的终端共享计算机，以虚拟技术把大计算机资源分割给以终端对应用用户使用**，这就是集中计算模式"

I marked in bold the part I consider more problematic. This is the proposal of Youdao but I don't think it's quite enough: "*By connecting simple terminals to share the computer, the large computer resources are divided to the application users by virtual technology*".

How would you translate it? Suggestions? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

"20 世纪60 年代，
In the 1960s,
计算机水平低、成本高,
computers were not very good, but expensive,
只能建以大计算机为中心的机房，
only centralised mainframe computer centres existed,
通过联接功能简单的终端共享计算机，
which could only be accessed via functionally simple terminals,
以虚拟技术把大计算机资源分割给以终端对应用用户使用，
using virtual technology to allocate the mainframe computer resource to the terminal user,
这就是集中计算模式"
this is known as the centralised computing method.

I still love my bash terminal and the ease and speed with which a simple bash script can do all kinds of tasks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a typo.

以终端对应**用**用户
以终端对应**的**用户